# C# Why use a repository as a property?

Tags: c#, repository

I am reading up upon the Repository usage. Sometimes I see that a repository is a property of an entity. I was wondering what the pro's and cons are.

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
  T GetById(int id);
  void Update(T);
}

public class FooRepository : IRepository<Foo>
{
  public Foo GetById(int i)
  { /* code ..*/ }

  void Update(Foo)
  { /*code..*/ }
}

public class Foo
{
   public IRepository Repository {get;set;}

   public void Update()
   {
     Repository.Update(this);
   }
}
```

Why use this apporach? Doesn't it makes more sense to use the repository and the entity object seperated? So that the entity object doesn't know about any repositories?

EDIT:

But what if you have one main object and different sub-objects:

```
public class MainObject
{
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public List<ISubject> SubObjects {get;}
}

public interface ISubObject
{
}

public class SubObjectA : ISubObject
{
  public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public int MainObjectId {get;set;}
}

public class SubObjectB : ISubObject
{
  public string AnotherProperty{get;set;}
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public int MainObjectId {get;set;}
}
```

So SubObjectA and SubObjectB are different types but implement the ISubject interface. The main object has a list of these subobjects. Each sub-object has it's own repository. How would you load the sub-objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some entity implementations require access to the context in which they are created, to implement lazy loading for example. Consider the following:

```
class MyEntity
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; private set; }
}

interface IMyEntityRepository
{
    ...
}
```

You can return sub-classes of MyEntity from the an MyEntity implementation, that require a reference to the repository that created it.

```
internal class MyLazyEntity : MyEntity
{
    public MyLazyEntity(MyLazyEntityRepository repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> Tags
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Repository.LoadTagsForEntityFromXml(this.Id);
        }
    }
}

class MyLazyEntityRepository : IMyEntityRepository { }
```

I would say, that keeping a reference to the source repository in a class derived from an entity is fine, on the other hand, the base entity class should not have knowledge about the repository.

Comment: In this case you have an entity which is a subclass. What I meant as an sub-object is a complete different object which doesn't inherit from base entity. However, all the sub-objects implements the same interface. Would the approach as you described be the same in this case?

Comment: Having a method named "Update" on your entity, means that it is not "persistence ignorant". If this is what you want, than requiring an IRepository set as a property is perfectly fine. If "Foo" is intended to be a POCO class with Persistence Ignorance, adding an IRepository as part of this class would be a violation of this ignorance.

Comment: if Foo is intended with Persistance ignorance. How would you implement this?

Comment: Than Foo shouldn't have a "Update" method and thus won't require a reference to the IRepository.

Comment: And how would you dynamic load the sub-objects? (see my first comment)

Comment: @Martijn I don't really get what you are up to. Can you edit your question to provide some more information?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use this method. Its not Foo's responsibility to update itself its the repository's responsibility. If you are applying persistent ignorance pattern.

This code is a smell:

```
   public void Update()
   {
     Repository.Update(this);
   }
```

It doesn't do anything but forward the call to repository.

Comment: But what if you want to dynamic load objects? Imagine that an object has a list of multiple sub-objects (which all implement the same interface) and must load the sub-objects' data?

Comment: @Martijn: A very nice approach to overcome that is to use dynamic proxies like NHibernate do. Then you don't need the repository at all, even when loading sub-objects.

Comment: But I'd like to know this without using NHibernate.

Comment: You don't need NHibernate, I'm just saying how NH does it. Dynamic proxies. Another way to load sub objects is to move that into the repositories also. repository.GetSubObjects(int parentObjectId);. Or even make the repository populate the entire object graph when fetching the root aggregate.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read good enough. I will read into Dynamic proxies. Sounds interesting.

Comment: @Martijn: It's like "J. Tihon"'s answer but making that code dynamic runtime.

Comment: @Martijn: By using dynamic proxies. See here for example http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html

Comment: @Martijn: I should point out that LINQ 2 SQL and Entity Framework also support lazy loading, so your options aren't just NHibernate. Are you trying to roll your own data access library? If so, for the love of God WHY!!??

Answer (score 0):

You can use that along with Spring http://www.springframework.net/

or another dependency injection util to load objects dynamically. As long as it implements the interface it works in the same way. Checkout Aspect orientated programming.

Have a look at the following post

[Pros and cons of DDD Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975657/pros-and-cons-of-ddd-repositories)